# Validation Errors when completing processes in Odoo

Tags: odoo-12, validationerror

Our company is currently using Odoo 12 and we are getting this validation error in a couple of different modules. When completing the final stage and only the final stage of a Manufacturing Order we receive this error in the picture below. The error also appears when trying to register a payment from an invoice. It seems to be thrown because an invoice or order is being finished and needs to change statuses but it only appears to be the final status change where we have the issue. Has anyone else run into this or could it be coming from some type of module setting?

[odoo error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFIMS.png)

Answer (score 0):

It can be hard to tell because it could be due to a routing issue which is tricky. I would search for all related records and see if anything else needs the record. Also, check your routing for the MO. It could be that you can't validate a MO due to another record needing to be processed first.